# What are output filters in Jetbrains IDEs?

Tags: phpstorm

The [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/output-filters-dialog.html) isn't particularly clear about what output filters for external tools do. What are the use cases for this feature?

Comment: Don't they do things like convert coffeescript to javascript?

Comment: @ChristianStewart: Oops, I forgot the hyperlink

Comment: What I was referring to was a file watcher, not the same thing.

Comment: It's a way to augment external tool output with "go to file/line" functionality. *"PhpStorm applies the specified filtering expressions against the console output of the external tool. As soon as a pattern is hit, its part that matches the $FILE_PATH$ will be treated as a path to a specific file and will be displayed as a link. When you click such link, the corresponding file is opened in the editor."*

Comment: Sorry, forgot that part. It's from [JetBrains Web Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/add-filter-dialog.html).

Comment: @DCoder: oh, I'm silly, I didn't see that there was a entry `add filter dialog` [below](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/add-filter-dialog.html)!

Comment: @Christian Stewart: output filters in external tools do exactly the same thing as those in file watchers: allow to parse the tool output making URLs clickable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output filters parse the output stream of your "external tool" command, making filenames clickable to open in the editor.